# Creating an IRC Message Queue

Tags: java, multithreading, message-queue, irc

I need a way to limit message count on my IRC bot to avoid a global ban from twitch for chat flooding. (They allow 100 messages/30 seconds)

There are two ways I considered doing this both involving a message queue.

1. Each message starts a thread which takes a counting semaphore. This thread then blocks for 30 seconds and releases after that time. This would be a very clean solution as the queue would be entirely managed by the OS which means less work for me, however, it may result in creating hundreds of threads. These threads will be sleeping for most of their lifetime, but I'm not sure if it considered okay to launch hundreds of threads that do nothing, effectively. They won't take up time slices from the scheduler when they are asleep but they would consume a lot of memory and there would be a lot of overhead in creating them.
2. Store a stack of timestamps and if a time-stamp is >30 seconds old remove it every time a message needs to be sent. Have a thread running that checks  the bottom of the stack every (10-50ms) to see if the time-stamp is >30 seconds old and remove if it is and then send a message from the highest position in the queue that has not been sent if it exists. When a message comes in to be sent it sends it immediately if there are <# messages in the queue.

1 has the downside of creating many threads that do nothing.

2 has the downside of needing 1 thread to poll the message list constantly.

2 could be improved to calculate the time needed to wait till the bottom message in the stack is 30 seconds old and send the message then, but I feel as if I am overcomplicating the problem at that stage.

Any thoughts on which would be the better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Create a sentMessage list with a date for each entry.

Check the list before posting a new message.

Comment: That's what I tried to do in '2'. I'll go with that in that case.

Comment: Yeah, i think thats the best implementation.